# Problems compiling under TeX Live 2017

Tags: tufte, texlive-2017

Trying to recompile my old master thesis which under `TeX Live 2015` and 2016 compiled just fine (I have a new computer that doesn't have said versions) but under TeX Live 2017 grinds to a halt.

The compiler stops at:

```
$[][]$\TU/TeXGyreHeros(0)/m/n/8 From Weitz-mann via
```

and I have no idea why. I cannot see anything out of the ordinary in the code and as far as I know other latex stuff compiles just fine under my current setup.

Any idea what to look for?

The whole log can be found [here.](https://pastebin.com/MpYZBQvg)

I'm using the `tufte-latex` book class via `lualatex` and `biblatex`.

---

simplified (plain tex) example

```
\input luaotfload.sty

\hsize=345pt

\font \r  = {name:TeX Gyre Pagella Regular:mode=base}  at 10pt
\font \i   = {name:TeX Gyre Pagella Italic:mode=base}   at 10pt

\r
P displaces the non-{\i ic5\/} pitches in a triad,
For the sake of examples, we assume the first chord in the
transformati

\bye
```

Comment: do you mean the log just stops at that point, with no error message?

Comment: Yes, my terminal just blinks pointlessly into the air and the cooling fans kicks in after 10 minutes or so. I tried leaving it for a few hours; same result. I have to abort the process manually. I get the same result either building with IDE's using latexmk or directly in terminal, which the log was cut from.

Comment: odd seems to be dying in `./mainmatter/part_1/01.nrt.tex` so I would put `\endinput` before line 88 of that file just to stop it getting there, see if that gets tex unstuck, then put it back bit by bit until you see what changed. luatex underwent big changes after 2015 going from 0.9x to 1.0x

Comment: I tried that and got to line 83 where I use a math thing: `\({I}\Leftrightarrow{i}\)` and the complier stopped with `Segmentation fault: 11`.

Comment: oops a segfault is never a user error If you could make a reproducible error the luatex team would no doubt like to see it (they are not so active here) you could mail to `luatex [at] tug [dot] org `

Comment: I managed to make a sort of mwe that returns the same error. Sent it to the dev team. I guess I'll just have to wait to see if I get a response.